# Regex to match pattern and also limit numer of characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I have a problem with regex to match pattern and also limit numer of characters:

For instance I have allowed number prefixes:
`2, 31, 32, 35, 37, 38, 39, 41, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58,  59, 60`

then I want numbers only and max length of whole of this to equal 9.
So for instance number like: `255555555` will be ok but `31555555555555555` will be not.

Here is my attempt to solve this but it doesn't  work as it should:

```
^( (2|31|32|35|37|38|39|41|46|47|48|49|50|51|52|53|54|55|56|57|58|59|60)+[0-9]* ){9}$
```

Comment: Be careful with your regex - if yours is exactly as you've posted it in your question, those spaces might be crucial - you can't pad regexes out with whitespace to make them look nicer, the whitespace will become part of it.

Comment: Not only that they eventually become part of it, they even will make some regex parsers throw errors if they are unquoted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a positive lookahead to limit (but not match) the prefixes and then match exactly 9 digits:

```
^(?=2|31|32|35|37|38|39|41|46|47|48|49|50|51|52|53|54|55|56|57|58|59|60)\d{9}$
```

Comment: This could be reduced

Comment: @Toto, doesn't matter. The principle is important. I'm not going to do character sets only to have OP need to search what I grouped if he wants to change the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this regular expression:

```
(^2\d{0,8}$)|(^(31|32|35|37|38|39|41|46|47|48|49|50|51|52|53|54|55|56|57|58|59|60)\d{0,7}$)
```

Here is a **[live example](https://regex101.com/r/ZYuX64/1)**.

---

If you don't generate this regex by numbers from somewhere, you can reduce it to:

```
(^2\d{0,8}$)|(^(3[125689]|4[16789]|5[0-9]|60)\d{0,7}$)
```

Here is a **[live example](https://regex101.com/r/ZYuX64/3)**.

Answer (score 1):

You could just test first the length and then the prefix.

```js
function check(s) {
    return /(?=^\d{1,9}$)^(2|3[125-9]|4[16-9]|5.|60)/.test(s);
}

console.log(['255555555', '31555555555555555', '33', '5a', '5', '50'].map(check));
```